# PaperJS importSVG from local file

Tags: node.js, svg, graphics, paperjs

Having recently resolved an issue I was having with PaperJS canvas I am currently trying to import an SVG via the project.importSVG() function.

I can successfully import a http addressed file such as this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg

However all local file uploads fail with 'error code 0'. I thought prepending the path with `file://` might do something, but no dice

Error code:

```
Error: Could not load "file:///Users/#####/Documents/####/########/green-leaf_final.svg" (Status: 0)
```

The javascript code I am using is:

```
project.importSVG("file:///a/path/to/file/green-leaf_final.svg", function (item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

N.B: a warning comes up for local files also saying:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///a/path/to/file/green-leaf_final.svg. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

Which personally seems even more confusing - I am not trying to read a remote resource, but perhaps the `file://` prefix is interpreted in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is more about general web hosting and web browsers than anything else.

Whilst this answer might not tell you directly why, any file being accessed from a remote origin (or even in your local machine), for specific browser request types, stops you from accessing this resource unless a 'CORS header' is included with within the origin.

Presumably, a local file system cannot supply this information, and as such you should host your file on localhost or another hosting means you have available in order to do it.

If you are already developing in PaperJS (and therefore likely have npm as a command-line tool) and this sounds daunting, then use `npm install http-server -g` and check the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for information about flags to provide and how to start the server. For this purpose you should navigate to the desired directory where your target file is in an OS command line shell and write `http-server -o --cors`.

The above command should serve all your current directory's files on localhost.